# ForEachAsync not run the tasks async

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

I follow the implementation here:
[ForEachAsync implementation](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/03/05/implementing-a-simple-foreachasync-part-2/)

So i have this method:

```
     public  static Task ForEachAsync<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int dop, Func<T, ConcurrentStack<FileInfo>, string, Task> body, ConcurrentStack<FileInfo> cStack, string fileName)
        {
              return  TaskEx.WhenAll(
                from partition in Partitioner.Create(source).GetPartitions(dop)
                select TaskEx.Run(async delegate
                {
                    using (partition)
                        while (partition.MoveNext())
                            await body(partition.Current, cStack, fileName);
                }));
        }
```

And i use it like:

```
var sw2 = new Stopwatch();
sw2.Start();
await rootDirTopLevelDirectories.ForEachAsync<string>(1, async (directoryPath, concurrentFoundedFilesStack, fileName) =>
                        {
                            await TaskEx.Run(() =>
                            {
                                Thread.Sleep(2000);
                            });

                            var f = string.Format("{0}*.{1}", fileName, "docx");
                            var sa = _fileSystemOperationsService.SearchForMostRecentFileUnderDirectoryByPattern(f, directoryPath, true, true);
                            concurrentFoundedFilesStack.Push(sa);
                        }, cStack, certFileName);

sw2.Stop();
Logger.GetInstance().Log(String.Format("ForEachAsync Takes {0}", sw2.ElapsedMilliseconds), System.Diagnostics.TraceEventType.Information);
```

Now the Stopwatch shown that it takes about 23 seconds and rootDirTopLevelDirectories contains 11 items which means that the threads run  sync. not async as (11 * 2 seconds) = 22 seconds. so do i miss something?

Comment: What is `TaskEx` here? As far as I know, that class only existed in a preview of the .Net Framework.

Comment: `TaskEx` was only used as a compatibility layer for .NET 4.0, which is *no longer supported*. The earliest supported .NET version is 4.5.2 where all this functionality is available from TPL classes or `async/await`. You  no longer need `ForEachAsync`

Comment: TaskEx here is related to Microsoft.Bcl.Async package which provides an equivalent to TPL functionalities to  .Net 4 https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/

Comment: @DavidG TaskEx was the name of Task in the Bcl.Async compatibility package for .NET 4.0, back when there was no built-in `async/await` support. Nowadays, it's .NET 4.0 that's unsupported

Comment: I am working on old project so i can't upgrade above than .NET 4

Comment: Oh wow, .Net 4, released nearly 8 years ago and no longer supported :/

Comment: @Marzouk why? What are you trying to achieve? Why use `await TaskEx.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(2000))`, that simply blocks a thread, it does *not* delay asynchronously. An async delay is provided by `Task.Delay()`. You gain nothing by `ForEachAsync`

Comment: @Marzouk furthermore, why don't you use `Parallel.ForEach`? If you don't want it to block, call it inside a `Task.Run`. Parallel.ForEach *doesn't* block the current thread, it *uses* the current thread for processing. If you don't want it to block the UI, use Task.Run

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i worked on single core virtual machine server which not support parallelism but async await can handle this by callbacks which will not achived using Parallel.ForEach

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I used Task.Delay which works great for me i think i missed the diffrence between Thread.Sleep() and TaskEx.Delay() thanks